# xml schema for Springbatch3.0.1?

Tags: spring-batch

i am trying to accomplish spring batch in spring 3.0.1 and  sufficient jars  have been included in the class path.when  i am trying to run the project with  **command line job runner** i am getting a error that shows  because  of miss match xml schema  for spring3.0.1. i have  3 differnt xml files as below

***ApplicationContext.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemalocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="JobRepository.xml" />
</beans>
```

***jobConfiguration.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemalocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="ApplicationContext.xml" />
    <bean abstract="true"
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep" id="taskletStep">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.mypackage.HelloWorldTasklet" id="helloTasklet">
        <property name="message" value="Hello World!" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="com.mypackage.HelloWorldTasklet" id="createdByTasklet">
        <property name="message" value="Created By Harish On Java" />
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" id="mySimpleJob">
        <property name="name" value="mySimpleJob" />
        <property name="steps">
            <list>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="helloTasklet" />
                </bean>
                <bean parent="taskletStep">
                    <property name="tasklet" ref="createdByTasklet" />
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

***JobRepository.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:batch="http://www.springframework.org/schema/batch"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xsi:schemalocation="  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd">
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository"
        id="jobRepository">
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
        <constructor-arg>
            <bean
                class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao" />
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="transactionManager"
        class="org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager" />
    <bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher"
        id="jobLauncher">
        <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
    </bean>
</beans>
```

***Java Code:***

```
public class HelloWorldTasklet implements Tasklet {
    private String message;

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    @Override
    public RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution,
            ChunkContext context) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println(message);
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
    }
}
```

my lib  contained following jars

```
com.springsource.org.aopalliance-1.0.0.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.lang-sources-2.1.0.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.commons.logging-1.1.1.jar
com.springsource.org.apache.log4j-1.2.15.jar
commons-beanutils-1.8.3.jar
commons-codec-1.3.jar
commons-collections-3.2.jar 
commons-digester-1.8.jar
commons-lang3-3.1.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
org.springframework.aop-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.asm-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.aspects-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.beans-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.context.support-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.core-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.expression-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
org.springframework.web.servlet-3.0.1.RELEASE-A.jar
spring-batch-core-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-batch-infrastructure-2.2.0.RELEASE.jar
```

any response  is appreciated greatly in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have the Spring Batch 2.2.0.RELEASE jars on your classpath, yet you aren't specifying that version in your schemas.  Update to use the versions and you'll be fine.

As a side note, is there a reason you are not using the schemas in your configuration?  While you're configuring batch components, you're doing it the hard way by not using the namespace or factory beans.  For example, instead of:

```
<bean
    class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository"
    id="jobRepository">
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobInstanceDao" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapJobExecutionDao" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapStepExecutionDao" />
    </constructor-arg>
    <constructor-arg>
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.MapExecutionContextDao" />
    </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

you can do this:

```
<bean id="jobRepository" class="org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="transactionManager" ref="transactionManager"/>
</bean>
```

We also have namespace support for the job configuration.  Instead of:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob" id="mySimpleJob">
    <property name="name" value="mySimpleJob" />
    <property name="steps">
        <list>
            <bean parent="taskletStep">
                <property name="tasklet" ref="helloTasklet" />
            </bean>
            <bean parent="taskletStep">
                <property name="tasklet" ref="createdByTasklet" />
            </bean>
        </list>
    </property>
    <property name="jobRepository" ref="jobRepository" />
</bean>
```

you should try this:

```
<batch:job id="mySimpleJob">
    <batch:step id="step1" next="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="helloTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
    <batch:step id="step2">
        <batch:tasklet ref="createdByTasklet"/>
    </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```

The namespaces handle some niceties like auto wiring the job repositories and transaction managers, etc.  I'd recommend you take a look at the Spring Batch documentation here: http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/2.2.x/reference/html/index.html

Comment: i have tried  for springbatch3.0.jar. but  i could find  it nowhere. can u  send me the link  for that?

Comment: Spring Batch 3 isn't out yet.  We released the first release candidate earlier this week.  You can find out what the latest versions of any project on http://spring.io/projects.   Spring Batch's page is here: http://projects.spring.io/spring-batch/